# how to get the value of an object inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have this array of objects:

```
$table=[{"count":"2","id_f":"2255"},{"count":"6","id_f":"5886"}];
```

I want to get the value of id_f of each object and check if this value exist in another array ,I tried with this but it gives me the wrong result:

```
foreach($table as $t){

    if (in_array($t[$id_f],$array){
     //dosomething}
     }else{
     //do something else

    }
 }
```

I also tried with this:

```
foreach($table as $t){

    if (in_array($t->$id_f,$array){
     //dosomething}
     }else{
     //do something else

    }
 }
```

I can't get the right result , I will appreciate any help.

Comment: `array = json_decode($table true)`

Comment: does `$t->id_f` works for you?

Comment: @OlegButuzov yes i tried this but it gives me this 'Trying to get property of non-object '

Comment: That is a question of _how_ you `json_decode()` that json string. I suggest you read the functions documentation...

Comment: @nourhein-chaieb so why in this case you saying you have array of objects? var is var_dump($t) saying to you?

Answer (score 1):

You dont show a `json_decode()` anywhere in your code, thats the first thing to do with a JSON String, to decode it into a PHP data structure. In this case an array of objects.

```
$other_array = array('2255', '9999');

$table='[{"count":"2","id_f":"2255"},{"count":"6","id_f":"5886"}]';
$array = json_decode($table);

foreach ( $array as $obj ) {
    if (in_array($obj->id_f, $other_array)) {
        echo 'Found one ' . $obj->id_f . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'No match for ' . $obj->id_f . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Results

```
Found one 2255
No match for 5886
```

Comment: thanks for replying, just a  notice the other array is an array of objects also , does that change anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without foreach loop:

```
<?php
$table=json_decode('[{"count":"2","id_f":"2255"},{"count":"6","id_f":"5886"}]');
$data = [10, 20, 2255];
array_walk($table, function($obj) use (&$data) {
    if (in_array($obj->id_f, $data)) {
        echo "+";
    } else {
        echo "-";
    }
});
```

The output obviously is:

> +-

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sure, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the dollar sign before your Object property name (actually, it won't work, except of course if `$id_f` is a real variable which has for value `'id_f'`, but somehow I doubt it) :

```
foreach ($table as $t) {
    if (in_array($t->id_f, $array){
     // do something
     } else {
     // do something else
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done like this:

to define the object array you can define like below with json string approach. or to define object is like this `$table = new stdClass();`

```
 <?php
$table='[{"count":"2","id_f":"2255"},{"count":"6","id_f":"5886"}]';

$obj = json_decode($table);

$array=array("2555","2255");
foreach($obj as $t){

       if (in_array($t->id_f,$array)){

         //dosomething

         }else{

         //do something else

        }

}

?>
```

Comment: sure give me moment.

Comment: Also this line `$obj = json_decode($table);` is creating an array of objects and not as your variable names suggest an object